# How to update dependencies version (e.g react) in package.json if using docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack

I'am trying to use webpack + reactjs to run a project. here are the main files:

```
# docker-compose.yaml
web:
  build: .
  ports:
  - "3000:3000"
  volumes:
  - .:/usr/app/selina-server:rw
  environment:
  - NODE_ENV=dev
  command: >
    sh -c '
      if test -d node_modules; 
      then 
        echo node_modules_exists ; 
      else 
        cp -a /tmp/node_modules /usr/app/selina-server; 
      fi && 
      npm install && 
      /usr/local/bin/node ./index.js
    '
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR "/tmp"

COPY ["package.json", "yarn.lock*", "./"]

RUN ["yarn"]

WORKDIR "/usr/app/selina-server"

RUN ["ln", "-s", "/tmp/node_modules"]

COPY [".", "./"]

RUN ["yarn", "run", "build"]

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample-docker-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node index.js",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node index.js",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Andyccs/sample-docker-webpack.git"
  },
  "author": "Andyccs",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Andyccs/sample-docker-webpack/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Andyccs/sample-docker-webpack",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.26",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-register": "^6.3.13",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-register": "^6.3.13",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "react": "^0.14.5"
  }
}
```

what i need to do (add command "npm update" in docker file?) if i want to update dependencies version in package.json?

Comment: Why would you want to run "npm update" since you're already using yarn? And you're already running "yarn"--if there's a version mismatch it'll already install the version supplied in package.json, no?

Comment: Docker is a container where you deploy your code. It's not a development environment so I am not sure why don't you update the packages in development and then your compose file picks up the updates from package.json when Docker makes the image.

Comment: I'm new to this, not familiar with yarn , if i update the package.json, should i need to restart the by using docker-compose down than up?

Comment: He means it is normally not advised to run npm and yarn at the same time. They are both package managers, so you'd normally choose one or the other. The Dockerfile is calling 'yarn' instead of 'npm'. Switch all instances of "yarn" for npm, and use the "npm install" command.

Comment: Every time you update any package whether, with npm or yarn, you will be/have to regenerating the docker image. Either you do it manually or depends on some CI/CD pipelines which do the same thing. You already have a `yarn` command which will pick packages from your package.json and make the docker image.

Comment: You should update the package in your local development environment and fully test it, especially for major version updates. The application and its dependent packages in the Docker image should be stable and version locked.

Answer (score 0):

As a couple of commenters have indicated, you should use a host-based Node environment for day-to-day development, and within that, you can use normal packaging tools.  Since your Dockerfile suggests you're using `yarn` as a package manager, [`yarn up`](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/up) will update the package metadata.

Having run `yarn up` on the host, you can then run `docker-compose build` to rebuild the Docker image, and the updated package dependencies will be reflected there.

The Docker image should be self-contained; you shouldn't need to bind-mount the application code into the container since it should already be present in your image.  That lets you simplify the Docker artifacts you show significantly, since there are a lot of workarounds to store the `node_modules` tree somewhere other than the rest of the application.  I'd write a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    # no volumes: or command: override
    # this is the whole file!
```

and a matching `Dockerfile`:

```sh
FROM node:latest

# Keep the node_modules directory in its normal place; don't
# install it somewhere else and try to link it in.
WORKDIR "/usr/app/selina-server"
COPY ["package.json", "yarn.lock*", "./"]
RUN ["yarn"]
COPY [".", "./"]
RUN ["yarn", "run", "build"]
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Comment: why  # no volumes: or command: override ?

Comment: Because the image should be self-contained, and you should be able to just run it without separately providing its code.  Both the code and the default `CMD` are provided in the Dockerfile.